# symfony getTable where clause as object

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

My table is using a Translation module

```
// This works fine for 1 item
$o = Doctrine_Core::getTable('myTable')->find(1);
echo $o->getName();
```

I want to be able to run a query and get all the rows with the name (which is in the translation table) correctly

```
$o = Doctring_Core::getTable('myTable').createQuery('a')
   ->leftJoin('a.Translation t')
   ->andWhere('a.visible = ?', true)
   ->andWhere('t.lang = ?', 'en')
   ->execute();
```

I want to be able to do

```
foreach($o as $item) {
  echo $item->getName();
}
```

But my getName() is always null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$item->Translation->name`, or alternatively you can create a similar proxy function:

```
//lib/model/doctrine/myTable.class.php
function getName() {
  return $this->Translation->name;
}
```

This function can be called explicitly like `$item->getName()`, or implicitly via `__get()` as `$item->name`;

I'm guessing you're using doctrine's behavior for storing translations - never used it, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Ok, the correct thing to do is to actually not do a leftJoin at all because the translation is handled automatically. Thanks for your answer.